# datatables-responsive set class for hidden column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to set a class name for one individual column in datatables. The problem is that all columns that are hidden by the datatables responsive extension don't have that class applied. I'm looking for a workaround/fix.

You can even see it on one of their examples:

https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-control/init-classes.html

Non-hidden `salary` column uses `desktop` class

```
$('.desktop').length;
12
```

Hidden `extn` column uses `none` class

```
$('.none').length;
0
```

Edit:

It looks like there has been an open issue on this since 2016.

https://github.com/DataTables/Responsive/issues/93

Any ideas for workarounds are still greatly appreciated though.

Here is a jsfiddle that shows what I am talking about.

http://jsfiddle.net/9n6qbcdr/

When you shrink the display horizontally the column `salary` is hidden. When the `salary` column gets hidden and then expanded, the column is no longer yellow.

Answer (score 1):

Because if class is `none` then DataTables remove this from table and shown Length: 0
You must change class e.g. `{ "data": "extn",       className: "hiddenColumn" }` and add css `display:none`

Comment: This solution only works when you want to hide the column manually by default. If datatables-responsive detects that the content won't fit on the screen and tries to automatically hide the column the `hiddenColumn` class is never applied.

Comment: [look this](https://ibb.co/f50Woz)  $('.hide').length return 12 and its invisible as ".none"

Comment: You linked an image

Comment: Yes, just to show that the table is responsive, it does not display column with 'hide' class and $('.hide').length return 12. Because that's what you meant?

Comment: I edited my post with a jsfiddle. I want the salary column to stay yellow even after it was "hidden" and then shown again by clicking the expand button.

Comment: Here is a jsfiddle with your suggestion http://jsfiddle.net/vpw71x5e/ ... The column is never yellow

Comment: Thanks man! There is one small bug that isn't that big of a deal. When the last column is hidden but the second to last column isn't -> you expand the row to show the last column -> then you resize the screen (to smaller) the column doesn't have the class applied. 
Here is a gif of the problem: https://imgur.com/a/8kt6B5C
Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5d39htj7/

Comment: I figured it out thanks for all your help. http://jsfiddle.net/6fhrLgjs/

Answer (score 0):

Based on Michał B's code this a solution

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <table class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">
  </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
td.customColumn{
  background-color:yellow;
}

.customColumn > .dtr-data{
  background-color:yellow;
}
```

Javascript

```
let dataSet = [
  ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "$320,800"],
  ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422","$170,750"],
  ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "$86,000"],
  ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "$433,060"],
];

let columnDefs = [{
  title: "Name"
}, {
  title: "Position"
}, {
  title: "Office"
}, {
  title: "Extn.",
  className: "customColumn"
}, {
  title: "Salary",
}];

let myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
  data: dataSet,
  columns: columnDefs,
  responsive: true,
}).on( 'responsive-display', function ( e, datatable, row, showHide, update ) {
        if(typeof row.selector.rows[0] !== 'undefined'){
        $(row.selector.rows[0].nextSibling).find('li[data-dt-column="3"]').addClass('customColumn');    
    }

}).on('responsive-resize',function( e, datatable, columns ){
        $(columns).find('li[data-dt-column="3"]').addClass('customColumn');
});
```